# Detect twitter iframe onload event?

Tags: jquery, iframe, twitter, onload

How can i get onload event of twitter iframe on my website (to set its height dynamically)?
I tried this, but console.log didn't fire.

```
$(".content-twitter").on("load", "iframe", function (e) {
   console.log('in');
})
```